# Unable to deploy a website which has a github dependency in "mix.exs"

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix

There's a dependency from github directly. It's not my repository. It's on github.

```
defp deps do
    [{:something123, git: "git@github.com:user123/something123.git"}
```

On localhost it's working well. However, on a server when I'm deploying it, throws a exception:

```
* Updating something123 (git@github.com:user123/something123.git)
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
** (Mix) Command "git --git-dir=.git fetch --force --quiet --progress" failed
```

What rights? Again, that repository isn't mine.

The code of this website I'm deploying is on github too, in someone's repository. It's all been well regarding deploying so far unit I added that dependency from github.

Comment: Is the dependency a public or private repository?

Comment: @MBuhot, public

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing to the built-in `github` syntax:

```
 {:something123, github: "user123/something123"}
```

Comment: IT'S WORKING WELL ON LOCALHOST with the current syntax! WHY NOT ON A SERVER?

Comment: I think it is the difference between git protocol and HTTPS protocol.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue with this example: `{:phoenix_swagger, git: "git@github.com:xerions/phoenix_swagger.git"}`

But this syntax works: `{:phoenix_swagger, git: "git://github.com/xerions/phoenix_swagger.git"}`